# Splitting data with irregular pattern

Tags: c#

Here are a few real sample data:

```
string s1 = "CLR DRBR|r 0004  BLCK|r 0006  WHIT|r 0006"
string s2 = "WGT WHGN|c 0004 YLGN|c 0006"
string s3 = "296  312|d 0004  137.2|n 0006"
string s4 = "HGT SH|r 0004"
string s5 = "ANLP  ANLP1 PNPL|r 0004"
```

The data will always come in the pattern: `[Group] [Value][Pipe + letter][Key]`, and the `[Value][Pipe + letter][Key]` part may be repeated multiple times.

Is there any way I can split this kind of data into something like:

```
string out1[] = { "CLR", "DRBR", "|r 0004", "BLCK", "|r 0006", "WHIT", "|r 0006" }
string out2[] = { "WGT", "WHGN", "|c 0004", "YLGN", "|c 0006" }
string out3[] = { "296", "312", "|m 0004", "137.2", "|n 0006" }
string out4[] = { "HGT", "SH", "|r 0004" }
string out5[] = { "ANLP", "ANLP1 PNPL", "|r 0004" }
```

Please note that the data pattern for s5 is slightly different from the others.

> > These are legacy data from the 1960s, so please don't ask me how/why they stored the data in this way. Thank you.

Comment: @48klocs I split according to | and a space, but it doesn't work for s5.

Comment: This looks to be parse-able with regular expressions.

Comment: @C.J. Please post the code of what you've tried so far, and what doesn't work.  Have you tried using `RegExp`?

Comment: @DanielPratt actually I was thinking of using that too, but I have never dealt with regular expression.

Comment: So the fields for out1 would be? 
`group, value, pipe+letter, key, value, pipe+letter, key`  
out1: `{ "CLR", "DRBR", "|r 0004", "BLCK", "|r 0006", "WHIT", "|r 0006" }`

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree yes, basically I just need to split all of them.

Comment: So the group is always at the beginning of a string; but based on `CLR` and `ANLP` i assume that group has no fixed length; or does it? So the first space in any given string signifies that the group has ended!? This is followed by `value|letter space key` in short `v|lsk` after a space multiple  `v|lsk` may follow: Example  `v|lsk` `v|lsk` `v|lsk`.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree The `group` does not have a fixed length, but we can determine that the `group` ends when it reaches the first space. However, the `values` do NOT have fixed length, and they may have spaces, thus I was unable to tell if the `value` has ended by an empty space

Comment: Seems pretty easy to me. First split by "|" pipe. For the first record find the first occurrence of a space and parse using substring.

Comment: @kevin Not possible. If splitting by "|", you will get `r 0004  BLCK` all toegether as one string, but `r 0004` and `BLCK` are 2 different entries

Comment: @cj - wrong CJ. 1) Split first by "|" then process the first record 2) process subsequent records differently. very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data you seem to have the following rules:

```
Phase 1 : Read to first space and split and remove space.
Phase 2 : Read to `|` and split prior to `|`.
Phase 3 : Include `|` and next 3 characters (space) and read to next space or EOT split and remove space if exists.
Goto Phase 2 if more data.
```

Like this (you probably want more error checking than I put in):

```
void Main()
{
  string s1 = "CLR DRBR|r 0004  BLCK|r 0006  WHIT|r 0006";
  string s2 = "WGT WHGN|c 0004 YLGN|c 0006";
  string s3 = "296  312|d 0004  137.2|n 0006";
  string s4 = "HGT SH|r 0004";
  string s5 = "ANLP  ANLP1 PNPL|r 0004"  ;

   splitit(s1).Dump();
}

string [] splitit(string input)
{

    List<string> output = new List<string>();

    int index = 0;

    // phase one
    while (input[index] != ' ') index++;

    output.Add(input.Substring(0,index));
    // skip space
    while (input[index] == ' ') index++;

    int indexTmp = index;

    do
    {
      // phase two
      while (input[index] != '|') index++;
      output.Add(input.Substring(indexTmp,(index)-indexTmp));

      // phase three
      indexTmp = index;
      index = index + 3; // save | code and space
      while ((input[index] != ' ') && index < (input.Length-1)) index++;
      output.Add(input.Substring(indexTmp,(index)-indexTmp));

      // skip spaces
      while (input[index] == ' ') index++;
      indexTmp = index;
    } while(index < input.Length-1);  

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I was struggling for this for 4 days, and you solved it in < 15 minutes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Using good tools helps, I recommend linqpad for fast prototyping of constrained problems.  Without it I would have taken longer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an accepted answer, but as long as you said my way won't work this is how I would do it:

```
int index;
List<string[]> output = new List<string[]>();
List<string> current = null;
string[] fields;

//i imagine this will be in an array when you read it in from a file
string[] input = new string[5];
input[0] = "CLR DRBR|r 0004  BLCK|r 0006  WHIT|r 0006";
input[1] = "WGT WHGN|c 0004 YLGN|c 0006";
input[2] = "296  312|d 0004  137.2|n 0006";
input[3] = "HGT SH|r 0004";
input[4] = "ANLP  ANLP1 PNPL|r 0004";
```

Now you just loop through to process the first record by itself, and for the subsequent records check if a second space occurs and process it properly.

```
bool first = true;

//loop through each of the input records
foreach (string record in input)
{
    //split the input records based on the pipe character
    fields = record.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //loop through each of the fields
    foreach (string field in fields)
    {
        if (first) //split the first field based on the first space in field
        {
            current = new List<string>();
            index = field.IndexOf(" ");
            current.Add(field.Substring(0, index).Trim());
            current.Add(field.Substring(index + 1).Trim());
            first = false;
        }
        else  //split subsequent records based on second space if it exists
        {
             index = field.IndexOf(" ", 3);
             if (index == -1)
             {
                 current.Add("|" + field);
             }
             else
             {
                 current.Add("|" + field.Substring(0, index).Trim());
                 current.Add(field.Substring(index + 1).Trim());
             }
        }
    }

    //control break processing
    first = true;
    output.Add(current.ToArray());
}
```

You could easily modify the inner loop to be another function.If you test I think this will be much faster.